# Is it possible to change the return value of a method in this case?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

I want to change the return value of method getvalue() to string "firefighter" which i tried from main method but did not work out.
looking forward to some soln.

```
public class Summ2 {
private String getValue() {
    return "TUHH";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Summ2 GO = new Summ2();
    assert GO.getValue() == "firefighter";
     System.out.println(GO.getValue());
    }


}
```

Comment: Voting to close as Typo / Of no value for future readers

Answer (score 2):

assert is a checking instruction, not a assignment one.

You can't get a new value from getValue() without using a member variable.